# Probability of a run of $n$ cards of the same color?

Tags: probability, card-games

A magician friend hit me with this one: given a shuffled deck, what is the probability that it contains at least one run of at least $n$ cards of the same color — for example, four reds or four blacks in a row?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to give an exact result, but if you want a simple upper bound, you can compute the expected number of runs of length $n$ easily.  Any given block of $n$ cards is a run with probability
$$
\frac{{{52-n}\choose{26}}}{{52}\choose{26}}=\frac{(52-n)!26!}{(26-n)!52!},
$$
so the expected number of runs of length $n$ is just
$$
E_n = (53-n)\frac{(52-n)!26!}{(26-n)!52!}=\frac{53\cdot {{26}\choose{n}}}{{53}\choose{n}}.
$$
(Here we are allowing non-maximal runs in the count... so a run of length $8$, say, contains three runs of length $6$.)  The expected number of runs of length $n$ is greater than or equal to the probability of there being *at least one* run of length $n$.  The first nontrivial result comes for $n=6$: the probability of at least one run of length $6$ satisfies
$$
P_6 \le E_6 = \frac{53\cdot{{26}\choose{6}}}{{53}\choose{6}}=\frac{26\cdot 25\cdot 24\cdot 23 \cdot 22\cdot 21}{52 \cdot 51\cdot 50 \cdot 49\cdot 48}=0.5315...
$$
Since the exact result is $P_6=0.46424\ldots$, this isn't too loose; and it will yield closer approximations for longer run lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  we have $m$  red and  $m$ black  cards and  we ask  about the
$(2m)!$ shuffled decks  containing a run of at least  $n$ cards of the
same  color. We  will  compute the  probability  of the  complementary
event, i.e.  there not being  a run of  $n$ colors or all  runs having
length at most $n-1.$

Using $z$ for red cards and  $w$ for black cards we have by inspection
that the count is $$[z^m w^m] G(z, w)$$

where $G$ is the generating function

$$G(z, w) = [z^m w^m] (1+\cdots+z^{n-1})(1+\cdots+w^{n-1})
\\ \times \sum_{q=0}^m w^q z^q
(1+\cdots+z^{n-2})^q(1+\cdots+w^{n-2})^q.$$

The  polynomials   that  appear  in  this   generating  function  have
$O(n^2  m^2)$ terms (contribution from the sum), in a different league
from the $4^m/\sqrt{\pi m}$ of the binomial coefficient.  Where we pay
is in the size of the  coefficients which are $m$ digits worst case.

As  an  aside note  that  we need  to  multiply  the coefficents  from
$G(z,w)$ by $(m!)^2$ because that is the number of decks corresponding
to a binary pattern of colors  where we have assumed that cards of the
same  color  and  value  but  from a  different  suit  are  considered
distinct.

In particular the  answer for a deck of cards where  we have $26$ reds
and $26$  blacks not  having a run  of length  four is (this  value is
exact)

$${52\choose 26}^{-1} 12911299418962
\sim 0.02603512182$$

so the probability that it does contain a run of length four is
$$97.4\%.$$

Obviously we  have not  checked all $495918532948104$  possible binary
sequences containing $26$ zeros and ones to obtain this answer.

Interestingly enough when we set $n=2$ and there are only two possible
candidates alternating between zero and one the formula produces

$$[z^m w^m] (1+z)(1+w) \sum_{q=0}^m w^q z^q.$$

As the terms in the sum  are matched in their exponents we must select
an equally  matched pair from the  product in front and  these are $1$
and $wz$ and we do obtain two as the answer when we match them to $z^m
w^m$ and $z^{m-1}w^{m-1}$ from the sum.

Finally observe that the formula  given above allows us to generate
sequences   for   fixed   $n$   and   consult  the   OEIS   for   more
information. These OEIS entries contain some very sophisticated closed
form  expressions that  show that  we  can find  formulas in  binomial
coefficients for $n$ fixed.

For example, not permitting runs of length $3$ yields
$$2, 6, 14, 34, 84, 208, 518, 1296, 3254, 8196, 20700, 
\\ 52404, 132942, 337878, \ldots$$

which is [OEIS A177790](https://oeis.org/A177790).

Similarly not permitting runs of length $4$ yields
$$2, 6, 20, 62, 194, 616, 1972, 6344, 20498, 66486, 216352,
\\ 705982, 2309246, 7569420, \ldots$$

which is [OEIS A177792](https://oeis.org/A177792).

The  reader who  wishes  to initiate  additional  studies of  these
numbers may  wish to  consult the following  Maple code where  a total
enumeration  routine is  presented  and the  generating functions  are
provided. To showcase these I point out that with $50$ cards each and
no runs of more than seven being permitted we get the value

$${100\choose 50}^{-1} 
52686377360486324043397253174$$

which gives $$47.78\%$$ for the complementary event (there is a run of
at least seven cards).

```
RL :=
proc(m, n)
    option remember;
    local iter, res;

    res := 0;

    iter :=
    proc(zc, oc, d)
        local  pos, cur, runlen;

        if zc = 0 and oc = 0 then
            cur := -1; pos := 1; runlen := 0;

            while pos <= 2*m do
                if d[pos] <> cur then
                    cur := d[pos];
                    runlen := 1;
                else
                    runlen := runlen + 1;

                    if runlen >= n then
                        break;
                    fi;
                fi;

                pos := pos + 1;
            od;

            if pos = 2*m+1 and runlen<n then
                res := res + 1;
            fi;

            return;
        fi;

        if zc >= 1 then
            iter(zc-1, oc, [op(d), 0]);
        fi;
        if oc >= 1 then
            iter(zc, oc-1, [op(d), 1]);
        fi;

    end;

    iter(m, m, []);

    res;
end;

Q1 :=
proc(m, n)
    option remember;
    local H;

    H := (1-z^n)*(1-w^n)*
    1/((1-z)*(1-w)-w*z+w*z^n+z*w^n-w^n*z^n);

    coeftayl(coeftayl(H, z=0, m), w=0, m);
end;

Q3 :=
proc(m, n)
    option remember;
    local K;

    K := add(z^q, q=0..n-1)*add(w^q, q=0..n-1)*
    add(w^q*z^q*add(z^q, q=0..n-2)^q*add(w^q, q=0..n-2)^q,
        q=0..m);


    coeff(coeff(expand(K), z, m), w, m);
end;
```

The following plot shows the  probabilities when we have sixteen cards
of each color. We get all configurations when we permit runs of length
at most sixteen, obviously.

```
1 +                                HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
  +                           HHHHH
  +                        HHH
  +                       HH
  +                     HH
0.8                    H
  +                    H
  +                   H
  +                  H
  +                 HH
0.6                 H
  +                 H
  +                H
  |                H
  +               H
  +               H
0.4              H
  +              H
  +             H
  +             H
  +            H
0.2            H
  +           H
  +          H
  +         HH
  +        H
  +********+-++-++-++-++-+-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-+-++-++-++-++-
0      2      4       6       8     10      12      14     16
```